# AKS Ingress controller DNS gives 404 error

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I have created aks cluster with 2 services exposed using Ingress controller

below is the yml file for ingress controller with TLS

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: xyz-office-ingress02
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - office01.xyz.com
    secretName: tls-office-secret
  rules:
  - host: office01.xyz.com
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: office-webapp
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /api/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: xyz-office-api
            port:
              number: 80
```

kubenctl describe ing

```
 Name:             xyz-office-ingress02
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        default
Address:          <EXTERNAL Public IP>
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  <default>
TLS:
  tls-office-secret terminates office01.xyz.com
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /(/|$)(.*)   office-webapp:80 (10.244.1.18:80,10.244.2.16:80)
              /api/        xyz-office-api:80 (10.244.0.14:8000,10.244.1.19:8000)
Annotations:  cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
              kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true
Events:       <none>
```

On IP i am able to access both services, however when using the DNS it is not working and gives 404 error

Comment: Are you sure DNS sends you to your IPs? Also, remove the first entry from your spec.rules (host.xxx, could be moved as spec.host?). OR remove the `-` in marking a second element in those rules: in your context, rules array should have only one entry.

Comment: Thanks for replying will make the changes, updated the question with ingress details

Comment: changing the yml by removing - worked thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning up remarks from comments: basically, the issue is with the ingress rules definition. We have the following:

```
  rules:
  - host: office01.xyz.com
  - http:
      paths:
        ...
```

We know connecting to ingress directly does work, without using DNS. While when querying it through DNS: we get a 404.

The reason for this 404 is that, when entering with a DNS name, you enter the first rules. In which you did not define any backend.

One way to fix this would be to relocate the "host" part of that ingress  with your http rules, eg:

```
spec:
  tls:
    ...
  rules:
  - host: office01.xyz.com
    http: #no "-", not a new entry => http & host belong to a single rule
      paths:
      - path: /(/|$)(.*)
        ...
      - path: /api/
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

*I have created the dns zone for the cluster*

[image]

*Created the namespace*

```
kubectl create namespace ingress-basic
```

[image]

*I have installed the helm repo and used the helm to deploy the ingress controller*

```
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \  
--namespace <namespace-name> \  
--set controller.replicaCount=2
```

[image]

*When I check in the logs I am able to see public IP with load balancer*

[image]

*I have created the some role assignments to connect the DNS zones*

[image]

*Assigned the managed identity of cluster node pool DNS contributor rights to the domain zone*

```
az role assignment create --assignee $UserClientId --role 'DNS Zone Contributor' --scope $DNSID
```

*I have run some helm commands to deploy the dns zones*

```
helm install external-dns bitnami/external-dns --namespace ingress-basic --set provider=azure --set txtOwnerId=<cluster-name> --set policy=sync --set azure.resourceGroup=<rg-name> --set azure.tenantId=<tenant-id> --set azure.subscriptionId=<sub-id> --set azure.useManagedIdentityExtension=true --set azure.userAssignedIdentityID=<UserClient-Id>
```

[image]

*I have installed the cert manager using helm*

```
helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \  
--namespace ingress-basic \  
--version vXXXX
```

*I have created and run the application*

```
vi nginxfile.yaml
 kubectl apply -f file.yaml
```

*I have created the ingress route it will configure the traffic to the application*
*After that we have to verify the certificates it will create or not and wait for few minutes it will update the DNS zone*

*I have created the cert manager and deployed that cluster*

```
kubectl apply -f file.yaml --namespace ingress-basic
```

*Please find this url for [Reference](https://blog.devgenius.io/externaldns-and-host-based-tls-ingress-in-aks-cluster-edf75fae36f3) for more details*

Comment: how does this answer question here? As suggested in comments below op's question: the Ingress object being used for this question is invalid, which perfectly explains why he's experimenting with 404: no backend defined. This is the only thing to look at. Article given doesn't give any sample of path-based routing setting up Ingress, which is irrelevant in this context. Finally: suggesting to use bitnami images in kubernetes also is a good indicator not a lot of thoughts went into setting this up. And please don't use screenshots, if you want to show us something, use a code block